# Show content on notification bar instead of an icon

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a foreground notification that displays a number. If I don't pull down the notification, all I can see is the icon I set to the notification. What can I do to display the number in place of the icon so it can be displayed without pulling down the notification panel.

This functionality is mostly implemented in internet speed meters to show your current speed.

What I basically want is to have a content (number) on the notification bar (not panel)[image: This is an example]

The counter at the first of the icons is what I'm trying to make. It shouldn't be as fancy as that one, but I need to have at least a number on there.

I.e I have tried to convert my text to a drawable and apply it as a small icon but on APIs 23- only drawable resources are supported

Comment: Could post a visual example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Barns I've added an image

Comment: In API 23 and above you can set `.setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap))`  So you can create your `Bitmap` on the fly and set the small icon as you need. (Unless I misunderstood and you need a solution for API below 23?)

Comment: @Barns yeah, I'm targeting 16+